# How to query for only certain attributes using Bookshelf.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

If I have two [Bookshelf.js](http://bookshelfjs.org/) models representing a simple users table:

```
const User = Model.extend({
  tableName: "users"
})

const Users = Bookshelf.Collection.extend({
  model: User,
})
```

How would I go about querying for only certain attributes. Like `SELECT name, age FROM ...` instead of the following which seems to simply do `SELECT * FROM ...`

```
Users.forge().fetch()
```

Comment: If you look at this issue: https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/202. They go over some statements and how Bookshelf.js translate the code into SQL. I'll keep looking, but this is the best example I've found. Also, you probably would be better doing `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE name = 'XXX' AND age = XXXX;`. If this helps, let me know and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: I don't want to add WHERE conditions. I want to `SELECT name, age` instead of the default `SELECT *`

Comment: There's apparently a `.columns()` method taken from knex that should do this. See here: https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/75 and check the documentation for more examples on using this.

Comment: The columns work. You can post an answer. And it's actually not a method, but seemingly putting { columns: ["name", etc] } as an argument to fetch